# OpenSSL win32 without libeay32.dll

Tags: c++, dll, openssl

I know that I must paste `libeay32.dll` file in the folder with my program which uses OpenSSL for windows. I only need one include: `openssl/evp.h`.

How can I compile my program without having to copy the `libeay32.dll`?

Answer (score 0):

DLL files are *dynamic* libraries. If a program or a lib ray was linked using dynamic libraries, then you need to have them accessible at runtime.

On the contrary, if a program or library was linked using *static* libraries, then they will be included in the executable or library and you won't need anything else at runtime (except maybe other external resources).

If OpenSSL depends on `libeay32.dll`, then it was compiled using dynamic libraries.
You might achieve what you want by recompiling OpenSSL using static libraries (if possible), and compile your program by linking statically to OpenSSL.